# Why the original data sets cannot be query out when updating to Version 1.0.1 of Apache IoTDB?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

I am now upgrading Apache IoTDB Version 1.0 to 1.0.1, and when I migrate the original data files, I directly replaced the data directory into the new version, but when I tried to query data, it seems like there is no data can be viewed. Anyone know why this occurr and how to correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the official website and seems like you can’t directly copy the data directory. You can migrate your original data by importing tsfile of Apache IoTDB.